# powershell csv capture the 1 value of three columns

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV with data presented like this:..

```
#date,a,b,c#
10,1,0,0
11,0,0,1
12,0,1,0
13,0,1,0
14,0,0,1
15,1,0,0
16,0,1,0
17,1,0,0
18,1,0,0
19,0,0,1
```

I want to capture the column values with "1"  Headers A,B,C only a "1" appears once on each line...
I want my output to be something along lines of

A,C,B,B,C,A,B,A,A,C

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Just iterate through each row (`$Row`) in the data table (`$data`)
- Collect all the concerned columns (`'a', 'b', 'c'`) that meet your
  requirements (e.g. `-eq 1`)
- Return the result if there is just one column that meets the requirement

```
ForEach ($Row in $Data) {
    $Header = ('a', 'b', 'c').Where{ $Row.$_ -eq 1}
    If ($Header.Count -eq 1) { $Header }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response! Wow  Thanks for walking me through how this was obtained.  Im giving correct answer to you for first response. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For each record in the CSV file, you'll want to loop through each column/header names until you find one where the column value for that record is `1`:

```
foreach($record in Import-Csv .\path\to\file.csv){
  'A','B','C' |Where-Object { $record."$_" -eq 1 } |Select-Object -First 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for walking me through how this was obtained.